# Print Value of pi. How many terms of this series do you have to use before you first get 3.14? 3.141? 3.1415? 3.14159?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    // Set the initial value of pi to 0
    double pi = 0.0;

    // Set the initial value of the term to 1
    double term = 1.0;

    // Set the initial value of the divisor to 1
    double divisor = 1.0;

    // Print the table header
    printf("%10s%25s\n", "Number of terms", "Approximation of pi");

    // Calculate and print the approximations of pi
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        pi += term / divisor;
        printf("%10d%25.10f\n", i, pi*4.0);
        term *= -1.0;
        divisor += 2.0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried to correct the  code but still can't get closer to the value as it is ask by my teacher in our assignment...

The Question is..
Calculate the value of π from the infinite series. Print a table that
shows the value of π approximated by one term of this series, by two terms, by three terms,
and so on. How many terms of this series do you have to use before you first get 3.14?
3.141? 3.1415? 3.14159?

Comment: What are you trying to do, *mathematically speaking*? Ignore the code for now. If you wrote things down on paper - what would it say?

Comment: I want the Value of pie.. How much term and series is need to get at the last to the value of pie..3.14? 3.141? 3.1415? 3.14159?

Comment: Note that 3.141 and 3.1415 are not rounded correctly by conventional means. They would be 3.142 and 3.1416.

Comment: If I remember correctly, this infinite series involves a multiplication by 4 (which I don't see in your code).  And I'm quite certain that 4 is not the appropriate initial value for the sum.

Comment: https://www.alamo.edu/contentassets/afe30946fa58450c89840c1173f3b9d0/sequences/math1314-arithmetic-sequences.pdf for the correct formula

Comment: @paddy yes I agree with you. But the question they are trying to ask i also can configure that is given to us by our teacher..

Comment: @SteveSummit I also have query related to question i can't figure what are teacher trying us to do...i also mentioned the question in just a few min back i corrected it

Comment: The code you have posted computes a series 3.66, 3.86, 3.72, 3.83, 3.74, ..., and never gets anywhere close to 3.14.  The correct sequence, I believe, is 2.66, 3.46, 2.89, 3.33, 2.97, ..., and gets to 3.14 after about 120 iterations.  You need to fix the code.  There are a number of hints here in these comments.

Comment: (a) The question about how many terms are needed looks like an assignment posed to a student, not a question you are asking Stack Overflow. What is **your** question? Edit your post to ask a specific question. (b) The computed sum never equals 3.14, 3.141, 3.1415, or 31.14159 because those numbers are not actually representable in the `double` format you are using. So the assignment probably intends to ask something about when the sum gets close to those numbers. But it is inadequately stated. You should ask the teacher what it means to “get” 3.14 or the other numbers.

Comment: @EricPostpischil thanks i will ask.. Yes it is typical type of a question for a newbie like me I  tried my best to figure the problem what our teacher want us to solve.

Comment: (c) One reasonable interpretation is to ask when you get within half of .01 to π, within half of .001 to π, within half of .0001 to π, and so on. The significance of these is that being within half the value of a certain decimal position means you have narrowed the result down to an interval as wide as that value, so it is somewhat like having computed the value to nearly that digit position. To implement that, simply compare each sum to the known value of π and ask if the absolute difference is less than the current target distance (half of .01, half of .001, and so on).

Comment: A simplified (but slow) way to do this is write a function that converts the value to a string (with `sprintf`) and then count the number of matching digits against a reference string. Out of curiosity, I tried this using a corrected formula, and found the series converges very slowly. Each additional digit requires about 10 times the number of iterations as the previous digit. Just 8 digits requires on the order of 20 million iterations. I would say that compounding floating-point rounding errors are gonna affect the accuracy of this series computation quite early on.

Comment: Although it's not as mathematically interesting as the approach Eric described, I would (a) fix the code to compute the correct sequence, and (b) change the line `for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++)` to `for (int i = 1; i <= 20000; i++)`, or perhaps `for (int i = 1; ; i++)`.  Then look for the first time you get a number that starts `3.14`, the first time you get a number that starts `3.141`, etc.  Because I'm a Unix geek, I did this by simply invoking things like `piprogram | grep 3.14 | head`.  (This gives some interesting false positives, like `3.1391416769` , because `.` is special to `grep`.)

Comment: @SteveSummit ok let me try it..

Comment: @SteveSummit  As you said it works on 200000 it gives finally 3.14159 value...Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> How many terms of this series do you have to use before you first get 3.14? 3.141? 3.1415? 3.14159?

The details of "first get 3.14" are a bit unclear.  Below attempts something like OP's goal and illustrates the slow convergence as computation time is proportional to the number of terms.

The high number of terms, each incurring round-off errors in the division and addition eventually render this computation too inaccurate for high term count.

```
int main(void) {
  double pi_true = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;
  double threshold = 0.5;
  int dp = 0;

  // Set the initial value of pi to 0
  double pi = 0.0;

  // Set the initial value of the term to 1
  double term = 1.0;

  // Set the initial value of the divisor to 1
  double divisor = 1.0;

  // Print the table header
  printf("%7s %12s %-25.16f\n", "", "", pi_true);
  printf("%7s %12s %-25s\n", "", "# of terms", "Approximation of pi");

  // Calculate and print the approximations of pi
  for (long long i = 1; ; i++) {
    pi += term / divisor;
    double diff = fabs(4*pi - pi_true);
    if (diff <= threshold) {
      printf("%7.1e %12lld %-25.16f %-25.*f\n", diff, i, pi * 4.0, dp++, pi * 4.0);
      fflush(stdout);
      threshold /= 10;
      if (4*pi == pi_true) {
        break;
      }
    }
    term *= -1.0;
    divisor += 2.0;
  }
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
                     3.1415926535897931       
          # of terms Approximation of pi      
4.7e-01            2 2.6666666666666670        3                        
5.0e-02           20 3.0916238066678399        3.1                      
5.0e-03          200 3.1365926848388161        3.14                     
5.0e-04         2000 3.1410926536210413        3.141                    
5.0e-05        20000 3.1415426535898248        3.1415                   
5.0e-06       200001 3.1415976535647618        3.14160                  
5.0e-07      2000001 3.1415931535894743        3.141593                 
5.0e-08     19999992 3.1415926035897974        3.1415926                
5.0e-09    199984633 3.1415926585897931        3.14159266               
5.0e-10   1993125509 3.1415926540897927        3.141592654   
5.0e-11  19446391919 3.1415926536397927        3.1415926536 
...
```

```
Ref                  3.1415926535897931
```

---

On a 2nd attempt, perhaps this is closer to OP's goal

```
int main(void) {
  double pi_true = 3.1415926535897932384626433832795;

  double threshold_lo = 2.5;
  double threshold_hi = 3.5;
  double error_band = 0.5;
  int dp = 0;

  // Set the initial value of pi to 0
  double pi = 0.0;

  // Set the initial value of the term to 4
  double term = 4.0;

  // Set the initial value of the divisor to 1
  double divisor = 1.0;

  // Print the table header
  printf("%12s %-25.16f\n", "", pi_true);
  printf("%12s %-25s\n", "# of terms", "Approximation of pi");

  // Calculate and print the approximations of pi
  for (long long i = 1;; i++) {
    pi += term / divisor;
    if (pi > threshold_lo && pi < threshold_hi) {
      printf("%12lld %-25.16f %-25.*f\n", i, pi, dp++, pi);
      fflush(stdout);

      char buf[100] = "3.1415926535897932384626433832795";
      buf[dp + 2] = 0;
      error_band /= 10.0;
      double target = atof(buf);
      threshold_lo = target - error_band;
      threshold_hi = target + error_band;
    }
    term *= -1.0;
    divisor += 2.0;
  }
  puts("Done");
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
             3.1415926535897931       
  # of terms Approximation of pi      
           2 2.6666666666666670        3                        
          12 3.0584027659273332        3.1                      
         152 3.1350137774059244        3.14                     
         916 3.1405009508583017        3.141                    
        7010 3.1414500002381582        3.1415                   
      130658 3.1415850000208838        3.14159                  
      866860 3.1415915000009238        3.141592                 
     9653464 3.1415925500000141        3.1415926                
   116423306 3.1415926450000007        3.14159265               
   919102060 3.1415926525000004        3.141592653              
  7234029994 3.1415926534500005        3.1415926535
```